# Convert MQ patch co commit in mercual

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mq

I've created MQ patch instead of commit.
How can I convert it to commit or rollback patch?

I am using mercurial 3.8.1 on Windows 10

Comment: @LazyBadger abort: no such help topic: qfinish

Comment: `hg help mq` ?! http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Mercurial_Queues#Turning_a_patch_into_a_permanent_changeset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted .hg/patches and rollback to previous commit.